# How FutureTask also acts like a latch?

Tags: java, concurrency

A quote from [JCIP](http://jcip.net/):

> "[FutureTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) also acts like a [latch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)."

- **How ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FutureTask.get()` will wait for the completion of the Task just like the `CountDownLatch.await()`. Both are blocking methods, but have overloaded variant to timeout.